# Assign inheritance chain inside constructor through prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

The following code is trying to implement inheritance by assigning prototype INSIDE the constructor, which fails as it prints 'undefined'. But if I move 'Derived.prototype = new Base();' out of the constructor, it works. I wonder the reason because it seems that 'Derived.prototype = new Base();' is also carried out by calling 'function Derived ()'. Thanks!

```
function Base () {
    this.name = '123' ;
}

function Derived () {
    this.derivedname = 'abc' ;
    Derived.prototype = new Base() ;
}

var DerivedObject = new Derived () ;

console.log ( DerivedObject.name ) ;
```

Comment: Among other problems, this would reassign the prototype on every call to `Derived`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: yes that's poor, but why would that alone break it?

Comment: No, that's a timing issue.  The prototype of the new object is assigned before you enter the constructor.  When you then reassign the prototype, you'r not working with the prototype of the **current** object, but of future ones.